# heatmap series is not update using setData()

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to change the heatmap series data using `setData()` when the     dropdown value is changed. Please check my working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/subhamoy/tpjf3qcg/3/)

When clicking on the second option from the dropdown then heatmap should `redraw()` with new series data.

Comment: All relevant code should be available on [SO], and not just as a link. That way, if the fiddle gets deleted later, the question will still be valid. That said, you have not said what is wrong, and what you expect to happen, so it is difficult to help you.

Comment: Either it works or it doesn't. If you have a working jsfiddle, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong data format in `setData` method, you have a few arrays - it should be one array , similar to `data` in series:

```
        chart.series[0].setData([

            [0, 0, 16],
            [0, 1, 14],
            [0, 2, 38],
            [0, 3, 24],
            [0, 4, 67],

            [1, 0, 92],
            [1, 1, 58],
            [1, 2, 78],
            [1, 3, 117],
            [1, 4, 48],

            [2, 0, 35],
            [2, 1, 15],
            [2, 2, 123],
            [2, 3, 64],
            [2, 4, 52],

            [3, 0, 72],
            [3, 1, 132],
            [3, 2, 114],
            [3, 3, 19],
            [3, 4, 16],

            [4, 0, 38],
            [4, 1, 5],
            [4, 2, 8],
            [4, 3, 117],
            [4, 4, 115],

            [5, 0, 88],
            [5, 1, 32],
            [5, 2, 12],
            [5, 3, 6],
            [5, 4, 120],

            [6, 0, 13],
            [6, 1, 44],
            [6, 2, 88],
            [6, 3, 98],
            [6, 4, 96],

            [7, 0, 31],
            [7, 1, 1],
            [7, 2, 82],
            [7, 3, 32],
            [7, 4, 30],

            [8, 0, 85],
            [8, 1, 97],
            [8, 2, 123],
            [8, 3, 64],
            [8, 4, 84],

            [9, 0, 47],
            [9, 1, 114],
            [9, 2, 31],
            [9, 3, 48],
            [9, 4, 94]
        ], true, true, false);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g3snLqwm/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: Thanks. it works for me.